# How to get a link library of ipa files downloaded from the app

Tags: ios

I download one ipa file from appstore,and want to get list of the static lib that linked,any one can help me ?

Answer (score 4):

First of all, it would be interesting to read [this official manual](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/MachORuntime/) by Apple (**OS X ABI Mach-O File Format Reference**).
Second: how do you download IPA from AppStore? I doubt it's practically possible. Anyway, if you somehow managed to get IPA, then you can use `otool` command line tool to get static imports. Look inside IPA file (it's standard zip-archive), find the binary file there (it usually has the same name with IPA, e.g, MyApp.ipa -> MyApp.app -> MyApp), extract this binary file and then run the command

```
otool -L MyApp
```